# W3C validation error if input accept attribute contains MIME type list

Tags: html, validation, file-upload

I try to use the accept attribute of an `<input type="file" ...>` element to limit the file open dialog to RTF files. Internet resources indicate that this attribute can contain a comma-separated list of extensions and MIME types. It actually works, but there is a validation problem:

This HTML5 code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="file" accept=".rtf, text/rtf, application/rtf, text/richtext" />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

causes this error with the [HTML5 validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

> Bad value .rtf, text/rtf, application/rtf, text/richtext for attribute
>   accept on element input: Expected a token character or / but saw ,
>   instead.

Is this a bug in the experimental HTML5 Conformance Checker of the W3C validator?

Comment: My first though would be to try it without the spaces. But additionally, w3 says: *"Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker.

The validator checked your document with an experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker. This feature has been made available for your convenience, but be aware that it may be unreliable, or not perfectly up to date with the latest development of some cutting-edge technologies. If you find any issues with this feature, please report them. Thank you."*  So it's not unthinkable that it would be an error.

Comment: Maybe .rtf isn't a valid media type? I couldn't find it in the list of valid media types: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: @jls The specification allows you to use extensions as well as mime types - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14994849/80901

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the validator. It doesn't accept file extensions. Fortunately, the validator itself contains a [link to report issues](http://validator.w3.org/feedback.html).

Comment: @GolezTrol the bug tracker for the HTML5 validator is at http://bugzilla.validator.nu/enter_bug.cgi - as it requires an account I will report it later

Comment: did you report the bug ? Could you please send a link to the bug report ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-accept),

> The `accept` attribute may be specified to provide user agents with a
>   hint of what file types will be accepted.
>
> If specified, the attribute must consist of a set of [comma-separated
>   tokens](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#set-of-comma-separated-tokens), each of which must be an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match
>   for one of the following:
>
> - The string `audio/*`
>     Indicates that sound files are accepted.
> - The string `video/*`
>     Indicates that video files are accepted.
> - The string `image/*`
>     Indicates that image files are accepted.
> - A [valid MIME type with no parameters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-mime-type-with-no-parameters)
>     Indicates that files of the specified type are accepted.
> - A string whose first character is a "." (U+002E) character
>     Indicates that files with the specified file extension are accepted.

I have tried the validator, and

- `<input type="file" accept="text/rtf, application/rtf, text/richtext" />` validates.
- `<input type="file" accept=".rtf" />` doesn't validate.

So the problem is `.rtf`, which should be accepted because it falls in the last category of allowed tokens.

Moreover, the spec provides this example, which doesn't validate

```
<input type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.xml,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document">
```

Then, it's a problem of the validator.